# NGUI 3.4.9 error NullReferenceException UnityEngine.Material..ctor (UnityEngine.Shader shader) UIDrawCall.CreateMaterial ()

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d, ngui

Editor is showing me `NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.Material..ctor (UnityEngine.Shader shader)
UIDrawCall.CreateMaterial ()`  again and again.  I am using NGUI 3.4.9 paid version.

If I use

```
var texture =  www.texture;
```

It shows me error. and if I use

```
var texture =new Texture2D(1,1); It is working fine.
```

I need to fetch image from url thats why I am using `www`. But if I fetch image from my resources then it is working fine. I was using previous version of NGUI(free) and the code was working impeccably and great. After when I updated my NGUI folder (package) with new one from that moment get this error again and again.

I guess it is not `www` kind of thing It is some NGUI rendering bug. But why it is occurring only with `www.texture`

Please guys help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

try change shader.Unlit - Transparent Colored.May be help you